# Non-interactive ssh disconnects immediately after login

Tags: ssh, router

I am trying to get some information from a Nokia router over ssh from a Linux machine.

The ssh works fine if I do this:

`ssh admin@10.0.0.1`

I can enter the password, log in, run commands.

However when I do the following, it disconnects me immediately:

```
ssh -v admin@10.0.0.1 'show time'

Verbose output:
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@10.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: show time
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 10.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2088, received 1840 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 488193.7, received 430209.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

It works fine if I use an expect script to connect, send password, and then send the command.

What could be wrong?

Comment: It really depends on what ssh server that router is running, also whether it successfully sets path etc for non-interactive sessions. My suspicion is that it runs an old version of dropbear which is known to have similar issues. You'll have to give a bit more info on the make, model and OS version to get to the bottom of it, if it's at all possible. http://dropbear.ucc.asn.narkive.com/LsaFu4PH/non-interactive-commands suggests others have similar issues with old dropbear.

Comment: http://www.alcatelunleashed.com/viewtopic.php?t=21551 A bit of googling shows an known issue and a workaround using a perl script, supplied by a third party. (Code review first to make sure it's not doing anything funky like sending your credentials off elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments.

In the end I ended up using expect as I am using a bash script to connect and pull the information.